# Creating multiple responses from one ASP page

Tags: asp.net, httpresponse, response.redirect

When the user checks a checkbox and clicks a specific button, I already do some stuff on the server and then use `Response.Redirect` to "reset" the page. I also have a function which allows me to "export" a datatable to an excel spreadsheet by using a `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` response.

Both of these work fantastically when separate. But, what I now need to do is have both events take place after one button click.

It seems like I would need to Flush the response after exporting to excel and then redirect the response afterward, but I can't seem to be able to get this to work. I could be way off on this one, and need some assistance. Thanks

**EDIT:**

Alright, I have decided to go about this by opening a new page (downloadexcel.aspx) which will then initiate the download and close after the download is completed. I am opening downloadexcel.aspx using javascript by writing it to the response of the current page. For some reason, however, the window is not being opened before the original page is re-directed. Is their a method to be called before I redirect? Maybe I have a syntax issue?

```
Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>window.open('~/DownloadExcel.aspx', '', ''); </script>")

        Response.Redirect("~/BulkImport.aspx")
```

Comment: This won't work, you cannot return 200 with the response body and 302 with new location in the same time. Try to rethink your approach.

Comment: You could add some javascript to the reset page to initiate the download (when a certain QueryString is present). i.e. `if (Request.QueryString['export'] == '1') { response.write("<script type='text/javascript'>window.open('<export url>', '', '_blank'); </script>"); }`

Comment: I have attempted this but running into an issue, see edit in OP please.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in a single HTTP request then you will have a single response. You can **either return** HTTP 200  (with the file as the content) or HTTP 301 to redirect the client. You can't return both.

The bottom line is that you will need to **rethink your approach**, you could "clean" the form on the client side using javascript instead of reloading the page using a redirect.